# AngularJS and jQuery conflict resolution

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I have built an AngularJS single page application in ASP.NET.  I added jQuery in order to send uploaded files to the server.  The code for this in jQuery is short and sweet and the solutions I saw in AngularJS seemed a lot more complex.  But now the website stops working when I include the jQuery CDN script tag.  In the Developer Tools console I see this error;

Error: k is undefined
n.event.remove@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js:3:6618

When I take out the jQuery script links the error goes away.  The links that I include for jQuery were these, placed before the AngularJS links:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>var jq = jQuery.noConflict();</script>
```

The noConflict method doesn't seem to solve the problem.  How would you correct this conflict?  Is there a solution that will keep jQuery in my application, or should I look again for a way to upload files using AngularJS?

Edit:

I'm loading these Angular scripts and everything else is my homegrown script:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular-route.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.9/angular-cookies.js"></script>
```

Comment: Always helps to use non minified version so you can see where in library source code that error gets thrown...then can look at what uses that method. noConflict is not likely to help...it is for `$` conflicts only. Also what inventory of scripts are being loaded? Doubtful that this has anything to do with mixing jQuery and and angular. What version of angular?

Comment: Best to put list in question itself where it can be formatted and read properly. Notice you are mixing angular versions

Comment: Good point.  I put the scripts at the bottom of the question.  As an update, I'm looking at AngularJS solutions for uploading the file.  That would eliminate my need for jQuery and solve this problem.  I will at least attempt to do that because it may simplify coding in the future too.  I already know how to do this in jQuery by itself.

Comment: Well first thing is make sure you use compatible angular versions...should all the same version number

Answer (score 0):

I found an AngularJS solution for uploading my file at:

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/angularjs/angularjs_upload_file.htm

So I removed the jQuery scripts from my application resolving this problem.